# How to use Tunable App Parameters in Injection Plugin for Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plugins, code-injection

I have configured Injection plugin in my Xcode 6.4 and I want to use “Tunable App Parameters” to dynamically see changes in my app as the tunable app Parameter changes. But I am not getting how to use the predefined precompiler macros (do I need to define those in my app or can I directly use them in my App?)

**Link for the plugin: http://injectionforxcode.com/**

It would be very helpful if someone knows how to use the Tunable App parameters?
(I am able to use the plugin’s main feature ie. getting updated changes without recompiling and re-running the App.)

Comment: anyone who can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, here comes the answer.

Injection Plugin also provides five variables and five colors, stored in global array INParameters and INColors respectively. In face, "Tunable App Parameters" just modify the two array contents.

Here is the flow: (Assuming you want to change a UIView's backgroubd color)

1. Product -> injection Plugin -> Patch project for Injection (which would add the following codes to your current target's pch file)
   [image]
2. `self.view.backgroundColor = INColors[0];`
3. Run your target
4. Product -> injection Plugin -> Tunable App Parameters (the first slideBar respones to the INColors[0], just change it)